# Don't Understand Why I am Getting Exception: Access violation reading location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, class, c-strings, strlen

I am working on a class that works with c-strings and I have created a member function that returns the length of the calling object (which is a c-string). When I run the code I get 
Exception thrown at 0x0F63F6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
I cannot figure out how to fix this. I am not quite sure how much code I need but hopefully the snippet below will suffice.

```
MyString::MyString(const char* aString) //memberString is a    c-string object
{
    memberString = new char[length() + 1];
    strcpy(memberString, aString);
}

int MyString::length() //Exception gets raised here
{
    return strlen(memberString); //Exception gets raised here
}
```

Comment: As you step through the code with your debugger, what does `memberString` equal where the exception occurs?

Comment: from the constructor it seems that `memberString` isn't null-terminated

Comment: How much code you need is a [mcve]. We can only guess from this bit and we certainly can't reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: You evaluate `length()` before setting `memberString` which reads `memberString`. Welcome to the UB world.

Comment: @freakish is right. you should've put `strlen(aString)` instead of `length()`

Comment: I replaced length() with strlen() and everything works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that

- `length()` need `memberString` to return size of stored data,
- `memberString` need `length()` to be created.

I think that your constructor should not rely on other member function.

What about:

```
MyString::MyString(const char* aString) //memberString is a    c-string object
{
    memberString = new char[strlen(aString) + 1];
    strcpy(memberString, aString);
}
```